# How to use FluentValidation in a generic way with DI in MVC controllers

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I implemented fluent validation rules. I am sending a request to my controller api endpoint via angular request in json format.

When I receive data and model parameter is populated I want to use fluent validation to validate sent data.

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]TesViewModel request)
        {

                    var validator = new TesViewModelValidator();
                    var result = await validator.ValidateAsync(request);

return Ok();

    }
```

How can I instantiate and access object and pass correct request in generic way with dependency injection?

Comment: Are you using Autofac for DI?

Comment: i am using structuremap

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using injecting IValidator instance and invoking it with:
var result = _validator.Validate(instance); where instance is T of registered AbstractValidator

Comment: You should at least post the solution you found out. Not just a text of how you did it,

Answer (score 1):

Create a Base abstraction class:

```
 public abstract class BaseApiRequest
{
}
```

Inherit your model with this abstraction class

```
public class YourModel : BaseApiRequest
{

}
```

After that create an extension method:

```
 public static bool IsValidApiRequest<T>(this T entity)
        where T : BaseApiRequest
    {
        var attribute = (ValidatorAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof(ValidatorAttribute));
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                return false;
            var validator = attribute.ValidatorType;
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(validator);
            MethodInfo method = instance.GetType().GetMethod("Validate", new[] { typeof(T) });
            object result = method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { entity });
            return (bool)result.GetType().GetProperty("IsValid").GetValue(result); ;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now, you can validate your request using:

```
 if (!request.IsValidApiRequest())
            return BadRequest();
```